# iOS 5 NSNumber Bug

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnumber

I will become crazy with this bug !
I have this piece of code which works well on iOS 4.3

```
newRegistered.ticket_id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:
[curRegistered objectForKey:@"ticket_id"] intValue]];
```

If I do :

```
NSLog(@"ID before : %d, ID after : %d",
[curRegistered objectForKey:@"ticket_id"] intValue], [newRegistered.ticket_id intValue]);
```

I Have on iOS 4.3 :

> ID before : 35459, ID after : 35459

And on iOS 5.0 :

> ID before : 35459, ID after : -30077

Please help !
Thank you for advance.

**##EDIT :##**
I have investigated a bit more the problem. It seems the problem comes from assigning a NSNumber in CoreData. I should have specified that the piece of code above is used with CoreData (newRegistered is a NSManagedObject, and curRegistered is a NSDictionary containing JSON Data (only strings, never int or long...)).

Here is the specific problem :

```
long long test = 789654;

Registereds *a = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Registereds" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
a.ticket_id = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:test];
NSLog(@"%lld -> %@", test, a.ticket_id); // Displays 789654 -> 3222 on iOS 5 and 789654 -> 789654 on iOS 4.3

NSNumber *ticket_id = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:test];
NSLog(@"%lld -> %@", test, ticket_id); // Displays 789654 -> 789654
```

So it seems the problem comes from the Registereds object (which is a NSManagedObject, like the newRegistered in the previous example).

Do you have any idea why this happens? I have never seen something like that in more than 2 years of coding, this bug really makes me think I don't know how to code...

Comment: You could try to use `[NSNumber numberWithLong: ...` to further investigate the problem.

Comment: You should probably print the "raw" value of `[curRegistered objectForKey:@"ticket_id"]` to see if there are any oddball characters present.

Comment: (I notice your first code snippet above is missing a '[', but I assume that's a copy/paste error.)

Comment: Try assigning the numeric value `[[curRegistered...` to a temp `int`, then using that `int` to set your `newRegistered` value, rather than doing it in one statement.  And make some other use of the temp `int` in your code to keep it from getting optimized away.  This smells of an optimization-related bug.

Comment: You're missing braces in both snippets, please match them properly, the top one is potentially ambiguous.  And if I am interpreting correctly where the brackets should be, why are you going from an `NSNumber` to an `int` and back to an `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hint: 789654 truncated to 16 bits is 3222.

I have tried to replicate your problem with iOS 5. The only way I can get `NSLog(@"%lld -> %@", test, a.ticket_id)` to display '789654 -> 3222' is if I set the ticket_id attribute type to `Integer 16`. If I set it to `Integer 32` or `Integer 64` then the expected value is displayed.

Check the attribute type for `ticket_id` in the data model editor. Because you are using `long long` I assume it should be set to `Integer 64`. From what you are showing I would suspect it is set to `Integer 16`. If not, then the value is getting truncated to 16 bits somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it... I stil wonder why it worked on iOS 4.3... Lets us think that Int 16/32/64 didn't have any effect...

Comment: iOS 5 is probably being more strict about enforcing the attribute type in-memory whereas 4.3 was letting it slip. I bet that even in 4.3 when the data is actually saved to the Sqlite database it is truncated.